# Primefaces doesn't show css and js

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, primefaces, themes

The application takes my tags and show me the page.
But in the view, I can't see the CSS and the JS. 
This is my code:

pom.xml

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- JSF -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PrimeFaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>afterdark</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<!-- faces-confg -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>
    WEB-INF/faces-config.xml,
        WEB-INF/manage-beans.xml,
        WEB-INF/navigation-rule.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- JSF THEME -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>afterdark</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- JSF Mapping -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Servlet de recursos de Primefaces -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

index.xhtml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:form>
    <f:loadBundle var="text" basename="i18n.applicationResources" />

    <ui:composition template="WEB-INF/xhtml/includes/mainLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            Leerroo lerro 


<p:panel header="Colors">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
            <h:outputText value="Inline: " />  
            <p:colorPicker id="inlineCP" value="#{colorBean.color1}" mode="inline" />  

            <h:outputText value="Popup: " />  
            <p:colorPicker id="popupCP" value="#{colorBean.color2}" widgetVar="picker"/>  
        </h:panelGrid>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to know that everything outside your `<ui:composition/>` tag will be ignored during page render. That means your `<h:form/>` and `<f:loadBundle/>` tags will not be processed if your template page is included in another page. That then leads to your current problem with the stylesheets:
2. It appears you're using a legacy version of primefaces, judging by the fact that you're registering a

   ```
    org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet
   ```

   If that's the case, your page should also have a  `<h:head/>` tag, to allow the resource servlet inject the necessary stylesheets and scripts in the view.

So putting all that together, you'll have:

```
<h:head/>
<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/xhtml/includes/mainLayout.xhtml">
<f:loadBundle var="text" basename="i18n.applicationResources" />
    <ui:define name="content">
        Leerroo lerro 
   <p:panel header="Colors">  
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
      <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="Inline: " />  
        <p:colorPicker id="inlineCP" value="#{colorBean.color1}" mode="inline" />  

        <h:outputText value="Popup: " />  
        <p:colorPicker id="popupCP" value="#{colorBean.color2}" widgetVar="picker"/>  
       <h:form>
    </h:panelGrid>

    </p:panel>
    </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
 </html>
```

Comment: I also like guess-it-yourself answers very much! Bravo! +1 :)

Comment: Lol @skuntsel! I was actually going to add the code eventually. Just looking at other questions first.